# my C# program doesnt download inline images

Tags: c#, email, inline, attachment

I process emails just fine. Now, I come across some emails that are PDFs and they must be inline since they aren't noticed with the .Attachments. Here is my code. I can't get it. Please help. Thanks!

```
var message = mainFolder.GetMessage(i - 1);

eCount++;
// Get specifics of email

var attachments = message.Attachments.ToList();

int attCnt = attachments.Capacity;

string preChk = message.From.ToString();

var msgMsg = new MimePart();

var att2 = new List<MimePart>();

var mp2 = new List<Multipart>();

var iter = new MimeIterator(message);

int mpCnt = 0;


if (attCnt == 0)
{

    while (iter.MoveNext())
    {
        mpCnt += 1;
        var mp = iter.Parent as Multipart;

        var prt = iter.Current as MimePart;

        if (mp != null && prt != null && prt.IsAttachment)
        {   //Check if an attachment slipped through

            mp2.Add(mp);

            att2.Add(prt);
        }
    }
}
```

// If I expand the iter.MoveNext, I can drill down to the images
[iter.MoveNext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZyQB.jpg)

Comment: That's great code (a little too much whitespace for my taste, but within reason), but how are we supposed to reproduce your issue without the email you're running this on?

Comment: Sorry about the whitespace. This is the first code thing Ive ever done and on my screen if I dont double space, then all the lines are connected. I will have to fiddle around with that in the future.....now to the email. Good question! I cant actually use my production email, due to confidentiality, but I will do a screen shot probably tomorrow (im about done for the day), and show you where they can be seen. Then maybe try to reproduce the issue with my own attachments. I know, complicated. Thanks for any help!

Comment: 911 got in the way. I might have figured it out...will let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out and I pretty much eliminated all the code above and condensed it to only a couple lines. In my var attachments, if it = 0, then I know its inline. I did this:

```
var bd = message.BodyParts.ToList<MimeKit.MimeEntity>();
```

Usually, we do the MimeKit.Mimepart attachment in attachments loop. I found out a couple things. Do var mp = bd.ElementAt(inAttCnt - 1);
var ma2 = mp.ContentType.Name; Check that ma2 <> null. Dont do a bd.Remove you will throw an exception! The foreach will take care of it! Hope that helps.